# Cassandra Delete issue

Tags: cassandra

If we deleted a row with a consistency level of QUORUM and all our reads are using the same consistency level , how the deleted records comes again.

For example in a 3 node cluster with RF=3 and Consistency level = QUORUM.

I have deleted a row with consistency QUORUM and one node is failed at that time. So the failed node is unavailable to catch up this delete.

Let Cassandra to delete rows in each node while full compaction. After rows are deleted from these two nodes , consider the failed node become alive.

Since our consistency level is QUORUM we will get zero result from one of any replica node and the coordinator can assume that the row is already deleted and return null to client.

My doubt is why cassandra wait upto gc_grace_seconds for performing a complete delete of rows from nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Because if the failed node recovers after the data has been completely deleted from the other 2 nodes, the cluster will not know whether the data has been deleted, while this node was down, or the data was inserted, but just failed to be replicated to the other 2 nodes for other reasons, for example, because these 2 nodes were up during the write, but then crashed and were replaced.

In other words, grace period gives enough time to have all nodes sync all data in any of these circumstances. And this is also why the round of repairs on the cluster needs to be completed within this grace period on a regular basis

Comment: Please currect if I am wrong .. I think that there is a timestamp in all tombstone and all tombstones that exceed gc grace period by calculating current time - time in tombstone will be deleted while amajor compaction.

Comment: If this is correct There are some  deleted recods which is going to exceed the grace period and how can we say that we may have to bring the failed node back before      grace period expire

Comment: Yes. The node needs to be back and repaired by the grace period, or out. Repaired because the tombstone must be replicated on that node before it is deleted from the other nodes

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. I need one more clarification .

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. I need one more clarification . Here is one example . Consider I deleted a row on today and my gc_grace is 10 days (Default) . After 10th day a major compaction will evict it. Here I can say that I have to bring back failed node before 10 days. But for  rows which are deleted 9 days before from today, Day after tomorrow is the last day and will be evicted. That means all days are important and how we can say I have a 10 day of time frame and I should bring those failed nodes before this duration?

Comment: That is why constantly repairing nodes in the cluster is a very important aspect of the Cassandra database maintenance. You want data in your cluster to be always in sync between nodes. Minor server hickups may or may not be fully covered by the hinted handoffs (I personally would not fully rely on that). But together with the constant repair job you can be sure that you during these 9 previous days, the servers had enough time to get all data repaired. But I would also say - if your server is down for a few days - it is safer to rebuild it.